# How to show wp.me shortlink underneath each post?

Tags: customization

What is the variable that holds the wp.me url? / What is the webservice / call that provides me the wp.me url? / What is the workaround to read that rel tag from the dynamic generator header (on a self hosted domain).

... to show it beneath each post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP 3.0 includes:

```
wp_get_shortlink()
```

which returns the ?p=1 style url for any post within your domain. This can be filtered, however for other shortening services, which is what the [Wordpress.com Stats plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/) does for self-hosted blogs. With that plugin installed and activated, wp.me shortlinks will be output instead of the default mydomain.com/?p=1, and can be retrieved with the function which can be used within the loop as:

```
echo wp_get_shortlink()
```

or to retrieve any post outside the loop:

```
$link = wp_get_shortlink($post->ID);
```

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that the stats plugin offers wp.me shortlinks.

Comment: it's not exactly well-documented - I noticed it by accident ;-)

Answer (score 0):

wp.me shortlinks are a feature of wordpress.com. The were introduced in this article: [WP.me — shorten your links](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/shorten/).

On a wordpress.com webblog you can make use of that feature. The button which reveals the shortlink gets it from the page source, the link is stored there within a hidden input element.

So I'm unaware how this should be possible to use on other sites then wordpress.com, sorry.